# How to resolve MySQLSyntaxErrorException exception?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, jdbc

I keep getting MySQLSyntaxErrorException when I create update jsp mysql.

```
String id_user = request.getParameter("id_login");    
String name_cust = request.getParameter("name_cust");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String no_phone = request.getParameter("no_phone");


Statement st = CON.createStatement();
//ResultSet rs;
int i = st.executeUpdate("UPDATE signup SET id_login='"+id_user+"',name_cust='"+name_cust+"', password='"+password+"'email='"+email+"',no_phone='"+no_phone+"', WHERE id_user='"+id_user+"'");
```

Comment: You really should be using a `PreparedStatement`, this is a SQL Injection attack waiting to happen!

Comment: And the first step, always, to fix a problem signalled by an exception, is to read the message and stack trace of the exception.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra `,` just before `WHERE` and you are missing one before `EMAIL`.

```
"UPDATE signup SET id_login=?, name_cust=?, password=?, email=?, no_phone=? WHERE id_user=?"
```

Also, you are supposed to use `PreparedStatement`, to avoid any SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect syntax in the SQL statement, try this

```
int i = st.executeUpdate("UPDATE signup SET id_login='"+id_user+"',name_cust='"+name_cust+"', password='"+password+"'email='"+email+"',no_phone='"+no_phone+"'WHERE id_user='"+id_user+"'");
```